# Android - savedInstanceState null when parentActivityName filled

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have an Activity that call another one by calling `startActivity()`, after some time `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` is called and I set a Boolean valeu to recover on the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` but when this method is called `savedInstanceState` comes null. I've searched the internet for an answer, but didn't find anything for my case.

Here's the `onSaveInstanceState` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState = new Bundle();
        outState.putBoolean(Constants.MAIN_ACTIVITY_STATE_RECREATED, true);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

The `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(R.string.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(Constants.MAIN_ACTIVITY_STATE_RECREATED, false)){
        return;
    }
    //DO SOME STUFF
}
```

And here's my AndroidManifest declaration of the Activities:

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the called Activity:

```
       <activity android:name=".PhotoUserActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
```

If I remove parentActivityName from the declaration of the second activity and make the "back button" by myself, the onCreate of the first Activity is never called.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you solved it? I have a same trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41578258/1639556 But I do not create nw bundle instance.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Unfortunately no, I have used another approach to achieve my objective

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to initialize the `outState` variable otherwise you wont be able to pass the vallue.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //outState = new Bundle(); <-- Remove this
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(Constants.MAIN_ACTIVITY_STATE_RECREATED, true);
    }
```

The outState `Bundle` is provided by the framework, by initializing it e.g. `new Bundle()` you are potentially dropping some value on that previous `Bundle` if it contains any.

It is always advisable to call the `super.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` first before adding new value.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the state of the application in a bundle (typically non-persistent, dynamic data in `onSaveInstanceState`), it can be passed back to `onCreate` if the activity needs to be recreated (e.g., orientation change) so that you don't lose this prior information. If no data was supplied, `savedInstanceState` is null.

> ... you
>   should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as
>   user edits) to storage. In addition, the method
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in
>   such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic
>   instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later
>   received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be re-created.
>   See the Process Lifecycle section for more information on how the
>   lifecycle of a process is tied to the activities it is hosting. Note
>   that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the
>   lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as
>   described in its documentation.

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)